# AngularJS working with $location.path and ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

I have this `$location.path` redirection:

```
myapp.controller('registerCtrl', function ($scope, $location, regService) {
  $scope.register = function() {
    $('#regbutton').prop('disabled','disabled');
    regService.createUser($scope.email, $scope.password, function(id) {
      if (id) {
        $('#register').modal('hide');
        $location.path('/account');
      }
    });
  }
})
```

When the redirection occurs it redirects the user to `http://myapp.com/#/account`

Now I want to display a different template to show the user account. So I'm trying to use `ngRoute` but cannot get it to work properly..

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$provide',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {
    console.log('in');
    $provide.decorator('$sniffer', function($delegate) {
      $delegate.history = false;
      return $delegate;
    });
    $routeProvider.
      when('/account', {
        templateUrl: 'account.html',

        resolve: {
          // I will cause a 1 second delay
          delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
            console.log('in resolve');
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
            return delay.promise;
          }
        }
      });
    $locationProvider
      .html5Mode(true)
      .hashPrefix('');
  }]);
```

Comment: '/account' won't match '/#/account', try defining the route just with '/account'

Comment: @Jens tried that.. doesn't work.. also edited my question to change ``/#/account/`` to ``/account``

Comment: Can't see anything else that is obvious from the code you posted... However, in Html 5 mode it should redirect you to "http://myapp.com/account", without the #... Is that correct... Have you from your debugger verified that "createUser" is running the callback correctly?... I can easily get location path to work in a simple sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/6OWZFE86PgU8aLbRfcxX?p=preview

Comment: @Jens what mode should I use if I want to accommodate routes that looks like ``/#/account``?

Comment: false, you can read about HTML5 vs. Old Mode here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: Try dropping the entire usage of $locationProvider for now, you should not need to play with html5Mode just yet, or the hashPrefix.

Also, can you see what is happening in the browser when it navigates to the /account? Does it make a request to load account.html? Finally, can you add an $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: 'some.html'}), where some.html is some other HTML file, to check if it is working? Do you have any other routes defined? Where does the first controller get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

The route you should be using in the configuration `when()` function is `/account`